# Looking for a way to clear content of TextView and display new content

Tags: java, android, textview

The following problem is giving me an headache. 
I created an TextView which displays a random array after clicking on a Button(askButton).
A second Button(rstButton) is supposed to act as a reset button, clearing all fields from text.To achieve this I used the `setText("")` method. It clears all fields successfully.

My problem is that after clearing said TextView and clicking the Button(askButton) then the TextView content stops being random and displays the same array over and over. I spent the whole day on various sites looking for a solution all day long on , without success.

```
 String ansArray[] = { "yes","no", "Surely","Never"}; 
    final Random random = new Random();                                         
    final int select = random.nextInt(ansArray.length);
    final TextView ansText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    Button buttonAsk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    buttonAsk.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        ansText.setText(ansArray[select]);
```

I think the "final" modifier causes the inability to change the array, but not declaring my array as final gives me an error and demands the final modifier.(I think here liesthe issue)

the second part of the code includes the reset Button:

```
final EditText questionText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ImageButton btnReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
           questionText.setText("");
            ansText.setText("");

    }
});
```

So does my issue lies in the final modifier or am I doing something else wrong? I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show a bit more code that is inside `buttonAsk.setOnClickListener`? I just want to see how you are getting a new random integer in your variable `select`, every time you click on `buttonAsk`. If its showing the same value, then its high possibility that `select` variable's value is not changing.  `A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement`. You can try and log the values and see yourself.

Comment: Above was all code i wrote so far. Honestly, I did not think about getting a new integer each time. I will look into this. Thanks!

Comment: If that's the issue then declare the variable `select` as a member variable and it won't have to be `final` to access in `listener`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "final" modifier :

```
final Random random = new Random();                                         
final int select = random.nextInt(ansArray.length);
```

these codes will always generate a single value every time you run your application.

good luck ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are only generating this number once. 
Get rid of the int select on the outside of the onClick listener.

```
final TextView ansText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
Button buttonAsk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
buttonAsk.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int select = random.nextInt(ansArray.length);
        ansText.setText(ansArray[select]);
```

What you did before was only get a random number once. With the random number being generated within the onClick, you will get a new random number for each new click.